# ionic 4, page transition hangs due to http call on ngOnInit

Tags: angular, ionic4

im building a app in ionic 4. when navigating from one page to another it is not going really fluent.

Im using `routerLink="/make-order/{{item.name}}" routerDirection="forward"` to go forward to the next page. On this (next) page in the ngOnInit function i do some http calls to get data. The problem is that this has effect on the page transition. its not fluent it hangs till data is loaded. How can i fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 ideas for workarounds:
1st you could move the init code to a different (later) Angular lifecycle hook.
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-examples

Possibly `AfterView` or `AfterContent`
Or using Ionic's hooks: `ionViewWillEnter`, `ionViewDidEnter`, `ionViewWillLeave`, and `ionViewDidLeave`

2nd you could add a delay to the observable using the delay operator.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delay.html

This should allow the transition to finish before making the request.

Further research:

I found this from the Ionic docs

```
Lifecycle Events
With V4, we're now able to utilize the typical events provided by Angular. But for certain cases, you might want to have access to the events fired when a component has finished animating during it's route change. In this case, the ionViewWillEnter, ionViewDidEnter, ionViewWillLeave, and ionViewDidLeave have been ported over from V3. Use these events to coordinate actions with Ionic's own animations system.

Older events like ionViewDidLoad, ionViewCanLeave, and ionViewCanEnter have been removed, and the proper Angular alternatives should be used.

For more details, checkout the router-outlet docs
```

https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration#lifecycle-events

Comment: A later hook helped, but eventually i disabled the transition  And now it is more fluent